# Show that $f(0)=1$ given that $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)\:\;\forall x,y\in\Bbb R$.

Tags: functions

The question is

> Let $f$ be a function with domain $\Bbb R$ that satisfies the conditions, $$f(x+y)=f(x)f(y),\;\text{for all $x$ and $y$ and $f(0)\neq0.$}$$ $(a)$ Show that $f(0)=1$.

The mark scheme says:
 from $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ for $x=y=0$ we have $$f(0+0)=f(0)f(0)\iff f(0)=\big(f(0)\big)^2$$ as $f(0)\neq0$, this implies that $f(0)=1$.

I don't understand this at all... can someone explain why this is?

Comment: What step don't you understand?

Comment: So $f(0)$ would imply that $x=y=0$, I understand that bit. But what is it about $f(0)\neq0$ that implies that f(0)=1?? What is the significance of $(f(0))^2$

Comment: You have that $f(0)=(f(0))^2$. Let $x=f(0)$; now you have $x=x^2$. What are the solutions to $x=x^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute $x=0$ and $y=0$ to get:

$f(0 + 0) = f(0)f(0)$

Simplifying we have:

$f(0) = f(0)f(0)$

Dividing both sides by $f(0)$ gives:

$f(0) = 1$

We are allowed to divide both sides by $f(0)$ because we are explicitly told $f(0) \ne 0$.

Comment: Perhaps more demonstratively, $f(0).f(0) - f(0) = 0$, so $f(0).(f(0) - 1) = 0$ having two solutions, 0 and 1. Since $\ne 0$ then must be 1.